# Java .jar file Run Differently from Command Line and File Explorer

Tags: java, file, jar

I recently wrote an application that is packaged as a .jar file. When I run the application from the command line via "java -jar MyProject.jar" everything looks perfect, just as it does when run from within eclipse. However when I go to the file location in the file explorer and double clock the file, it doesn't quite work. All of the functionality is there, but the GUI is not quite right. All text is much larger, despite the application not changing size, when run like this, to the point where much of it is cut off.

Anyone know whats going on? Thanks!

Comment: Is this happening on the same box/same OS/same user?

Comment: also, more important, you need to check which java version (and path to the executable) is running from the command-line and file explorer.

Comment: Yes to the same box/OS/user. How can I check which java version ir running from the file explorer?

Comment: Depends on particular OS/File explorer, you can google it. Alternatively, you can a make a simple java code that reports java path and version and pack it into jar.

Comment: This is definitely the problem. Running from command line it uses JRE 1.8.0_172, running from file explorer it uses JDK 10.0.1. At the risk of sounding like a complete idiot, what is the best way to make file explorer use JRE?

Comment: You didn’t happen to set all of your GUI components’ sizes with explicit pixel values instead of letting the layouts do their job, did you?

Comment: No, I just used a GridLayout and let it do its thing

Comment: @JakeR97 you might need to google it for your OS/File Explorer. For example, for windows the executables associated with file extensions used to be in the registry (pardon my ignorance, haven't touch windows for several years).

Comment: @JakeR97 from the other side, you need to decide which JDK versions you need to support

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue was that when being run from the command line, the program was being run with JRE 1.8.0_172, however when being run from the file explorer, the program was using JDK 10.0.1